# How can I change directory text color in C shell?

Tags: command-line, ls, text, color-management, csh

I want to change directory color in cshell. So I copied /etc/DIR_COLORS file to my ~$home and named .dir_colors. I modified that file but it doesnt change the text color. If I source that file then terminal shows Command not found about the number of the colors. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by *"directory color"*, exactly? Are you referring to the output of the `ls` command? If so, are you actually specifying color options to the ls command (in bash, the default ~/.bashrc does that for you by aliasing `ls` to `ls --color=auto`).

Comment: Directory color means directory text color. Its default blue now , and I want to change it to the red. I mean I want to change the default colors of my directory, file,  etc....

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 steps to getting custom color output in directory listings:

1. create an `LS_COLORS` environment variable containing the color specifications
2. invoke the `ls` command with colors enabled ex. `ls --color=auto`

In Ubuntu's default bash configuration, these steps are performed in the ~/.bashrc file:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    .
    .
    .
fi
```

To do the equivalent in ~/.cshrc you would need to change everything into csh syntax:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if (-x /usr/bin/dircolors) then
    if (-r ~/.dircolors) then
        eval "`dircolors -c ~/.dircolors`"
    else
        eval "`dircolors -c`"
    endif
    alias ls 'ls --color=auto'
endif
```

Note the use of `dircolors -c` in place of `dircolors -b` in order to output the `LS_COLORS` variable assignment in a form suitable for `eval`uation by the C shell.

Comment: Thank you ! May I know -x and -r mean in the if syntax?

Comment: They are *file tests* (or *file enquiries* if you're using the BSD implementation of csh): `-r` means the file exists and is readable; -x means it exists and is executable, the same as their bash equivalents.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!